# AWS SNS Pricing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I have some questions about AWS SNS pricing.

https://aws.amazon.com/sns/pricing/

> Includes publish, topic owner operations, and subscriber operations, **but not deliveries**

I am sending push notification to device.

1. Is it counted as 2 operations? Sending + deleivery?

> Includes **publish, topic owner operations, and subscriber operations**, but not deliveries

2. Get or list are counted as operations?

I am registering device. This is one operation. 
Now I am recreating device registration, but it has same token, so new endpoint is not created.

3. Is it counted as operation? Same for subscriptions? Same for topics?

I have 5 device endpoints, all of them are subscribed to one topic.
Now I am sending message to the topic.

4. How many operations does it cost me? 6 (1 sending + 5 delivery)? 10 (5 sending + 5 delivery)? Another number?

I have 5 device endpoints, all of them are subscribed to one topic. 4 of them are disabled. I am sending message to the topic.

5. How many operations does it cost me?
6. Am paying something for storage of disabled device endpoints? Or should I clean them? Does delete endpoint counted as operation?

** *Operation = operation that costs money*

Answer (score 1):

Every **API call** is one **operation**. (My assumption, but that's the norm.)

You will be charged the **delivery charge** for each enabled subscriber to a topic when a message is sent to the topic. That is, every time that Amazon SNS is expected to delivery a message to one recipient.

Comment: Thanks for help. But I am still wondering how things are work in case of disabled devices. Device disabled, subscription enabled for example?

Comment: I don't quite understand your scenario, but my assumption is that you would be charged for every message that SNS attempts to send to a subscriber. I'm not sure how retries would be counted (presumably it's part of the send charge, but I do not know).

Comment: My scenario is pretty simple. I register device with token (app + device) and subscribe it to the topic. Now app version is changed, so token regenerated. I register it again and subscribe it again. Now I have one enabled and one disabled device arns. And two subscriptions.